# How to get all tweets (more than 100) and associated user fields in python using twitter search API v2 and Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get all tweets and their associated user fields (username, name,...etc) that match a certain query using search_recent_tweets. I tried to use pagination and flattening but it only flattens the tweets (not the user fields). So I am trying to implement something like next_token in get_user_tweets but search_recent_tweets doesn't have pagination_next? How can I do this?

This is the code I am trying to use

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy

BEARER_TOKEN = ''
api = tweepy.Client(BEARER_TOKEN)

response = api.search_recent_tweets(query = 'myquery',start_time = '2022-09-19T00:00:00Z', end_time = '2022-09-19T23:59:59Z',
                              expansions = ['author_id'],
                              tweet_fields = ['created_at'],
                              user_fields = ['username','name'],
                              max_results = 100)
tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(response.data)
metadata = response.meta
users = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in response.includes.items()}, axis=0)
users = users.reset_index(drop=True)
users.rename(columns={'id':'author_id'}, inplace=True)
all_tweets = tweet_df.merge(users)
next_token = metadata.get('next_token')
while next_token is not None:
    response = api.search_recent_tweets(query = 'myquery',start_time = '2022-09-19T00:00:00Z', end_time = '2022-09-19T23:59:59Z',
                            expansions = ['author_id'],
                            tweet_fields = ['created_at'],
                            user_fields = ['username','name'],
                            pagination_token=next_token,
                            max_results = 100)
    tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(response.data)
    metadata = response.meta
    users = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in response.includes.items()}, axis=0)
    users = users.reset_index(drop=True)
    users.rename(columns={'id':'author_id'}, inplace=True)
    tweets = tweet_df.merge(users)
    all_tweets.append(tweets)
    next_token = metadata.get('next_token')
    
all_tweets
```

Comment: any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GTdownloader for that:

```
from gtdownloader import TweetDownloader

# create downloader using Twitter API credentials
gtd = TweetDownloader(credentials='twitter_keys.yaml')

gtd.get_tweets('myquery', 
               lang='en', 
               max_tweets=100,
               start_time='09/19/2022', 
               end_time='09/20/2022'
               )

# accessing tweets data frame
gtd.tweets_df.head()
```

See docs at https://gtdownloader.readthedocs.io/

Edit:
Disclaimer, I wrote this code for my research